# Spring: how to get an applicable generic bean instance by its type argument(s)?

Tags: java, spring, generics

I'm using Spring 4.1.2 and I have the following code:

```
public class Foo {
}

public class Bar {
}

public interface Service<T> {
}

@Service("fooService")
public class FooServiceImpl implements Service<Foo> {
}

@Service("barService")
public class BarServiceImpl implements Service<Bar> {
}
```

I know that Spring 4 can inject generic bean instances like the following:

```
@Autowired
private Service<Foo> service; // works fine
```

But I need to obtain them in a static way like the following:

```
Service<Foo> service = getService(getContext(), Foo.class);

...

public static <T> Service<T> getService(ApplicationContext context,
        Class<T> objectClass) {
    ...
}
```

I tried to use `ApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(Service.class)` but it returns all available bean instances (`fooService` and `barService`). So I need to pass type arguments somehow.

Is there any way to do this? Something like this:

```
@SupressWarnings("unchecked")
Service<Foo> service = applicationContext.getGenericBean(
        Service.class, // bean class
        Foo.class // type arguments
        // ...
);
```

Comment: Use `@Qualifier` when you autowire a dependency.

Comment: And how do you think I'll do that in a static way, like in the method `getService()` above?

Comment: why do you require beans statically when they are made available correctly via `@Autowired` ??

Comment: Because I'm using `WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(ServletContext)` to access `ApplicationContext` and there are no more ways to obtain it. So I need a static way to get such a bean.

Comment: Why would you need a static way? If you only need to inject it just use the `getAutowireCapableBeanFactory` and use that to autowire the dependencies in the class you construct (instead of trying to look them up yourself).

Answer (score 4):

Getting generic beans programmatically from the application context:

```
String[] beanNames = applicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(ResolvableType.forType(new ParameterizedTypeReference<String>() {}));
if (beanNames.length > 0) {
    String bean = (String) applicationContext.getBean(beanNames[0]);
}
```

or in your specific case:

```
String[] beanNames = applicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(ResolvableType.forType(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Service<Foo>>() {}));
if (beanNames.length > 0) {
    Service<Foo> bean = (Service<Foo>) applicationContext.getBean(beanNames[0]);
}
```

Or check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49700833/329589) answer if you're interested in a mechanism to handle generic objects with particular handler.

Comment: Wow.  great answer.  i edited to disambiguate the "String" for the bean-name and the "String" for the thing for which one is fishing the Ioc-Container (applicatonContext in spring-beans).