# Spring: how to get bean from application context which implements generic interface?

Tags: java, spring, generics, dependency-injection

I have interface:

```
public interface CommandHandler<T extends Command> {
    void handle(T command);
}
```

There are commands which implement **Command** marker interface

```
public class CreateCategoryCommand implements Command {
}

public class CreateCategoryCommand implements Command {
}
```

For each **command** I have apropriate **CommandHandler** implementations:

```
@Component
public class CreateProductCommandHandler implements CommandHandler<CreateProductCommand> {
    @Override
    public void handle(CreateProductCommand command) {
        System.out.println("Command handled");
    }
}

@Component
public class CreateCategoryCommandHandler implements CommandHandler<CreateCategoryCommand> {

    @Override
    public void handle(CreateCategoryCommand command) {

    }
}
```

**Question:**
I have command bus

```
@Component
public class SimpleCommandBus implements CommandBus {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void send(Command command) {
        // OF COURSE, THIS NOT COMPILED, BUT I NEED SOMETHING LIKE THIS
        CommandHandler commandHandler = context.getBean(CommandHandler<command.getClass()>)
    }
}
```

How to get bean from application context which implements generic interface with particular type?

Comment: @Autowired
private CommandHandler<CreateProductCommand> createProductCommandHandler; Did not work for you ? or Autowired
private List<CommandHandler<?>> commandHandlers; to get them all ?

Comment: I need to get CreateProductCommand class dynamically. I don't want to put @Autowired private CommandHandler<COMMAND_TYPE> for each command type in SimpleCommandBus class.

Comment: Did u notice my updated comment about how u can autowired them all as a list   @Autowired List<CommandHandler<?>> commandHandlers; You could also do applicationContext.getBeansOfType(CommandHandler.class>

Comment: Yes, thanks. Ok, I've got all command handlers. How can I get particular command handler for given Command (e.g, Command child) from this list? For example, how can I get CommandHandler for CreateProductCommand?

Comment: for particular implementation applicationContext.getBean("createProductCommandHandler ");

Comment: I think we misunderstood each other. 1) I have list of CommandHandler<T extend Command> 2) I have particular command CreateProductCommand implements Command. 3) How can I get CommandHandler<CreateProductCommand> from list of CommandHandlers? Assuming that "CreateProductCommand" is dynamic parameter, instead, it might be CreateCategoryCommand, etc...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125026/discussion-between-branko-ilic-and-moreo).

Answer (score 1):

Way I solved it:

```
@Component
public class SimpleCommandBus {

    private final Logger logger;
    private final Set<CommandHandler<?>> handlers;
    private final Map<Class<?>, CommandHandler<?>> commandHandlersCache = new WeakHashMap<>();

    public SimpleCommandBus(Logger logger, Set<CommandHandler<?>> handlers) {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.handlers = handlers;
    }

    public void send(Command command) {
        CommandHandler<Command> commandHandler = getCommandHandler(command);

        if (commandHandler != null)
            commandHandler.handle(command);
        else
            logger.error("Can't handle command " + command);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <C extends Command> CommandHandler<C> getCommandHandler(C command) {
        Class<?> commandType = command.getClass();

        if (commandHandlersCache.containsKey(commandType))
            return (CommandHandler<C>) commandHandlersCache.get(commandType);

        for (CommandHandler<?> haandler : handlers) {
            Class<?> supportedCommandType = resolveTypeArgument(haandler.getClass(), CommandHandler.class);

            if (commandType.isAssignableFrom(supportedCommandType)) {
                commandHandlersCache.put(commandType, haandler);
                return (CommandHandler<C>) haandler;
            }
        }

        commandHandlersCache.put(commandType, null);
        return null;
    }


}
```